# My CustomDeserializer class doesn't work second time that is used on second field of a same class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I'm using Jackson dependencies, I think the issue is when jsonParser is called more three times. but I'm not sure why it is happening that....
I have this case:

```
@Entity 
public class Car implements Serializable {

   @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserialize.class)
   private Window windowOne:

   @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserialize.class)
   private Window windowSecond:
   ....//Getters/Setters


}
```

CustomDeserializer class

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Window> {

  .....  // constructors


@Override
public Window deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
    String field = jsonParser.nextFieldName();
    String nextField = jsonParser.nextFieldName();
      return new Window("value1", "valu2");
    }
}
```

Manager class which call objectMapper

```
 public class Manager {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    public void serializeCar(ObjectNode node) {
         // node comes loaded with valid values two windows of a Car.
         // All is OK until here, so this treeToValue enters to CustomDeserializer once only.
         // treeToValue just read the first window ?  because of second window is null and the first window enters on mode debug. 
         Car car = mapper.treeToValue(node, Car.class);
     }

 }
```

When I debug I don't know why treeToValue(objectNode, class) just calls one time to the CustomSerializer class and second time doesn't call it.
Please what is wrong here? or why mapper.treeToValue ignores the second field using CustomDeserializer?. 
Thanks in advance, experts.

***UPDATED***

I added a repository as example:

https://github.com/NextSoftTis/demo-deserializer

Comment: can you share a poc for this bug in github please ?

Comment: I think, it's no necessary. Because you have the classes as example, but if you really need it, I'll create it .

Comment: i use the same config for one of my applicatoins, but i can not spot wath is wrong with yours, if you can create a github repo with juste wath needed to reproduce, i will for sur try to fix it for you

Comment: Oh nice, but this is due to jackson stuffs, ok I'm going to create it..

Comment: done https://github.com/NextSoftTis/demo-deserializer

Comment: hi, i validate the solution of Raniz

Comment: @LhoBen what do you mean?

Comment: Good job on the example repository by the way. Having a runnable example available makes it _a lot_ easier to answer questions!

Comment: @Raniz I appreciate your answer. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your deserialiser is not working properly.

When you reach *windowOne* you're reading the names of the next two fields - `"windowSecond"` and `null` (since we're out of tokens) - instead of the values of the `JsonNode` you've read. When the serializer returns, Jackson then sees that there are no more tokens and skips deserialisation of *windowSecond* because there is no more data to consume.

```
@Override
public Window deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
    String field = jsonParser.nextFieldName();
    String nextField = jsonParser.nextFieldName();
    return new Window(field + nextField, jsonNode.getNodeType().toString());
}
```

You can see this by looking at the output of your example program:

```
{
    "windowOne": {
        "value1": "windowSecondnull",
        "value2": "OBJECT"
    },
    "windowSecond": null
}
```

(your sample repo does not contain the same code you posted here by the way).

The lines:

```
String field = jsonParser.nextFieldName();
String nextField = jsonParser.nextFieldName();
```

is the issue, you should use the `JsonNode` you've read instead and it'll work as expected:

```
@Override
public Window deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
    String value1 = jsonNode.hasNonNull("value1") ? jsonNode.get("value1").asText() : null;
    String value2 = jsonNode.hasNonNull("value2") ? jsonNode.get("value2").asText() : null;
    return new Window(value1, value2);
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "windowOne": {
        "value1": "Testing 1",
        "value2": "Testing 2"
    },
    "windowSecond": {
        "value1": "Testing 1 1",
        "value2": "Testing 1 2"
    }
}
```

**In-depth Explanation**

To elaborate on what exactly happens in the original code, let's take a simplified look on what happens in the JSON parser:

The constructed `JsonNode` that we're parsing represents the following JSON:

```
{
    "windowOne": {
        "value1": "Testing 1",
        "value2": "Testing 2"
    },
    "windowSecond": {
        "value1": "Testing 1 1",
        "value2": "Testing 1 2"
    }
}
```

The parser [tokenizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token) this to allow us to work with it. Let's represent the tokenized state of this as this list of tokens:

```
START_OBJECT
FIELD_NAME: "windowOne"
START_OBJECT
FIELD_NAME: "value1"
VALUE: "Testing 1"
FIELD_NAME: "value2"
VALUE: "Testing 2"
END_OBJECT
FIELD_NAME: "windowSecond"
START_OBJECT
FIELD_NAME: "value1"
VALUE: "Testing 1 1"
FIELD_NAME: "value2"
VALUE: "Testing 1 2"
END_OBJECT
```

Jackson the goes through these tokens, trying to construct a car out of it. It finds `START_OBJECT`, then `FIELD_NAME: "windowOne"` which it knows should be a `Window` deserialised by `CustomDeserialize` so it creates a `CustomDeserialize` and calls it's `deserialize` method.

The deserialiser then calls `JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);` which expects the next token to be a `START_OBJECT` token and parses everything up until the matching `END_OBJECT` token, returning it as a `JsonNode`.

This will return a `JsonNode` that represents this JSON:

```
{
    "value1": "window 2 value 1",
    "value2": "window 2 value 2"
}
```

And the remaining tokens in the parser will be:

```
FIELD_NAME: "windowSecond"
START_OBJECT
FIELD_NAME: "value1"
VALUE: "Testing 1 1"
FIELD_NAME: "value2"
VALUE: "Testing 1 2"
END_OBJECT
END_OBJECT
```

You then call `String field = jsonParser.nextFieldName();` which is documented as:

> Method that fetches next token (as if calling nextToken) and verifies whether it is JsonToken.FIELD_NAME; if it is, returns same as getCurrentName(), otherwise null

I.e. it consumes `FIELD_NAME: "windowSecond"` and returns `"windowSecond"`. You then call it again, but since the next token is `START_OBJECT` this returns null.

We now have

```
field = "windowSecond"
nextField = null
jsonNode.getNodeType().toString() = "OBJECT"
```

and the remaining tokens:

```
FIELD_NAME: "value1"
VALUE: "Testing 1 1"
FIELD_NAME: "value2"
VALUE: "Testing 1 2"
END_OBJECT
END_OBJECT
```

Your deserialiser turns this into a `Window` by passing `field + nextField` (`="windowSecondnull"`) and `jsonNode.getNodeType().toString` (`="OBJECT"`) and then returns, passing control of the parser back to Jackson which first sets `Car.value1` to the window your deserialiser returned, and then continues parsing.

Here's where it gets a little weird. After your deserializer returns, Jackson is expecting a `FIELD_NAME` token and since you consumed the `START_OBJECT` token it gets one. However, it gets `FIELD_NAME: "value1"` and since `Car` doesn't have any attribute named `value1` *and* you have configured Jackson to ignore unknown properties it skips this field and it's value and moves on to `FIELD_NAME: "value2"` which causes the same behaviour.

Now the remaining tokens looks like this:

```
END_OBJECT
END_OBJECT
```

The next token is `END_OBJECT` which signals that your `Car` has been properly deserialised so Jackson returns.

The thing to note here is that the parser still has one remaining token, the last `END_OBJECT` [but since Jackson ignores remaining tokens by default](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS) that doesn't cause any errors.

If you want to see it fail, remove the line `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`:

> Unrecognized field "value1" (class com.example.demodeserializer.Car), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "windowSecond", "windowOne"])

**Custom deserialiser that consumes tokens**

To write a custom deserialiser that calls the parser multiple times we need to remove the line `JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);` and handle the tokens ourselves instead.

We can do that like this:

```
@Override
public Window deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    // Assert that the current token is a START_OBJECT token
    if (jsonParser.currentToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
        throw dc.wrongTokenException(jsonParser, Window.class, JsonToken.START_OBJECT, "Expected start of Window");
    }

    // Read the next two attributes with value and put them in a map
    // Putting the attributes in a map means we ignore the order of the attributes
    final Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put(jsonParser.nextFieldName(), jsonParser.nextTextValue());
    attributes.put(jsonParser.nextFieldName(), jsonParser.nextTextValue());

    // Assert that the next token is an END_OBJECT token
    if (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        throw dc.wrongTokenException(jsonParser, Window.class, JsonToken.END_OBJECT, "Expected end of Window");
    }

    // Create a new window and return it
    return new Window(attributes.get("value1"), attributes.get("value2"));
}
```

Comment: Looks good, I have a question regarding when you do several calls to jsonParser in deserialize method, that is the main issue I think so, do you know why I can't call several times to jsonParser to do some logic..?

Comment: Yes, I have the same question that @nextsoft is talking about,  is not it correct to call many times jsonParser? or why something pass that...

Comment: I couldn't fit an explanation into a comment so updated the answer